# How to extract field value from another field that is of type Object

Tags: java, sqlite

I'm new to java reflexion and I'm trying to integrate SQLite with java.

I have 2 objects Person and Department. There is relation OneToMany between them.

As I'm working on save functionality (SQLite) I want to extract field names and its values so I can build full query. I have no problem with extracting names and values of  fields that are of primitive type (String, int etc.). I have problem with type of Object (in this case it is Department field in Person object).

I'm able to print object but unable to access its fields (namely **pk**).

Could you help me please?

**METHOD FOR EXTRACTING FIELDS**

```
// method for extracting fields
private StringBuilder getFieldsWithValues(Object entity) throws IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException {
        StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();

        for (Field field : entity.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            System.out.print((field.getName() + " - "));
            field.setAccessible(true);
            // TODO: eliminate if statement from for cycle
            if (field.isAnnotationPresent(ManyToOne.class)) {
                // HERE I want to extract the pk value from Department object
                System.out.println(field.get(entity));
            } else {
                System.out.println(field.get(entity));
            }
        }
        return query;
    }
```

**DEPARTMENT OBJECT**

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Department {
    @Id
    private long pk;
    private String name;
    private String code;

    public Department() {
    }

    public Department(String name, String code) {
        this.name = name;
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Department %d: %s (%s)", pk, name, code);
    }
}
```

**PERSON OBJECT**

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    private long id;
    private String surname;
    private String name;
    private int age;

    @ManyToOne
    private Department department;

    public Person(String surname, String name, int age) {
        this.surname = surname;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Person() {
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public Department getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(Department department) {
        this.department = department;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Person %d: %s %s (%d)", id, surname, name, age);
    }
}
```